# Alternative to multi level context menu

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, architecture

I am working on a web application. The exact problem I am facing is much complex (I am not working with tables), but I can present it abstracted as follows:

I have a number of tables, each table having a number of lines, and each line having a number of cells.

Let's say I am currently viewing table 1. I want to somehow let the user link a cell from this table, to a cell from another table. The only kind of approach I can imagine is one where I attach a multi level context menu to each cell of the table with the following structure (example for table 1 cells):

```
 - Table 2
   - Line 1
      - Cell 1
      - Cell 2
      - ...
      - Cell n
   - Line 2
   - ...
   - Line n       
 - Table 3
   - Line 1
      - Cell 1
      - Cell 2
      - ...
      - Cell n
   - Line 2
   - ...
   - Line n   
 - ...
 - Table n
   - Line 1
      - Cell 1
      - Cell 2
      - ...
      - Cell n
   - Line 2
   - ...
   - Line n
```

But as even bootstrap got rid of the submenus, I imagine this is not the most user-friendly solution.

They specifically say:

> Submenus just don't have much of a place on the web right now,
>   especially the mobile web. They will be removed with 3.0

Taking into account this, my questions are:

1. Is there a better approach for my specific case?
2. Considering this "just don't have much of a place on the web right now", what are developers using instead? Are there any alternatives?
3. Can I avoid the need for the multi level context menu in the first place?

Comment: How exactly do you want to implement associating a cell from one table with a cell from another.  Is it just in the UI, like highlighting both/all cells, or will that association need to be processed on the back end?

Comment: It is just a form of navigation, in the UI. Starting from a cell in one table, then selecting a cell in the other. The backend is aware only of the selected pair of cells. Each cell having an unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as a two-step process, have the user select the first part of the link, then select the second part.

When they click on the first part, put a variable into context that holds it, and have some sort of display like this to display that context:

```
***************************************
*          Linking:                   *
* R13,"<ColumnName>" to:   ????       *
*  <cancel>                           *
***************************************
```

Then, when you click the second link, you can make the link, prompt them to confirm, etc...

You can feel free to use my awesome ascii art in your webapp :-)